# How to select files with specific patterns in command line?

Tags: linux

I have some zipped fastq files in a directory that I need to analyse. The files in the directory are as below:

```
...
9065_S257_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz
7119_S189_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz  
9012_S223_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz  
9066_S258_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz
...
test.txt
test.html
Undetermined_S0_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

I figured that I can use `*_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz` to select the .fastq.gz files, but I don't want to select the `Undetermined_S0_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz` file. Is there any way to do that? Thank you!

p.s. I need those files to do `zcat *_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz | ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the examples, you could use the glob pattern:

```
zcat [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_S[0-9][0-9][0-9]_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz | ...
```

(Starting with 4 digits followed `S_`then another 3 digits, then the common file suffix).

Or could just be:

```
zcat [0-9]*_S[0-9]*_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz | ...
```

Basically, the glob depends on the prefixes of the files that you do wan to include.

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly I was wondering. I wanted to specify digits before "_S"!

Answer (score 0):

```
ls *.fastq.gz | egrep '^[0-9]+_S.*' | xargs zcat
```

Answer (score 0):

Let advanced filename expansion capability do the work for you.

If using `bash` or `ksh93`:

```
zcat !(Undetermined)_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz | ...
```

(Assuming the `extglob` option is turned on, which it is for interactive shells)

If using `zsh`:

```
zcat *_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz~Undetermined* | ...
```

(Assuming the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option is turned on. The first one also works for `zsh` if `KSH_GLOB` is turned on.)